# std::ostream to QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading

I have overloaded '<<' operator for MyClass.

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const MyClass& Obj);
```

Now I want to convert std::ostream to QDataStream rather than converting MyClass to QDataStream.

```
friend QDataStream operator << (QDataStream& out, std:ostream&);
```

Something like this.
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Er? You're trying to create an opeator for storing *output streams* in a `QDataStream`? That doesn't seem possible, and certainly doesn't make much sense. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `std::ostream` is like a connection to send (one way) data to somewhere. You can't read from it as if it were the data itself.

Comment: I want to convert std::ostream to QDataStream. That's it.

Comment: `operator<<` does not convert one type to another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just convert one into the other. But you can use `QBuffer` as a workaround. It is a `QIODevice`, so you can create a `QDataStream` from it. When done writing your data, get the `QByteArray` from the buffer and use its data to write to your `std::ostream`.