# how to get ostream if I have << and >> operator overloaded already

Tags: c++, qt, iostream

I have a class named myClass. It has overload operator << and >>. I can use it with cin and cout objects. Now I want to write object of this class to a file in Qt. How can I get its buffer to play with. Convert to QTextStream, QDataStream whatever is possible OR suggest me any solution.
Thanks
like

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331120/stdostream-to-qdatastream ?

Comment: You can have multiple overloads of the same operator with different operand types.  Depending on how you've written things, they may need to be friend functions as opposed to class members.  You might also look at the link @user1781290 gave above.

Comment: How can I use ostream and istream except cin and cout?

Comment: For example cout<<myclass;
it convert myclass into stream and display it. But I need that stream to playwith, convert into Qt Stream.

Comment: Maybe you want to try a stringstream? But I still don't get what you are actually trying to achieve...

Comment: friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, myClass&);
friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream&, myClass&);
it works fine. but how can I use it apart from cin and cout????

Comment: @NoorNawaz You want to forbid using it with `cin` and `cout` but have implementations for `std::ostream` and `std::istream` operators?? I don't get it ...

Comment: I want to convert myClass in QDataStram or QTextStream. but I can't edit myClass. I would have to do something with its returned istream ostream only.

Comment: @NoorNawaz Best you edit your question and show a code sample, where you want to go and where you're stuck.

Comment: You can not convert an `istream` or `ostream` to provide the data in a way that is suitable for `Q*Stream` - they are both streams, and not containers for the data as such. So one solution as suggested above is to use your existing stream output operators to convert to output to a `stringstream`, and then output the actual string to the `Q*Stream`.

Comment: @NoorNawaz If I understand you correctly, then you think that `<<` and `>>` are conversions of your object to streams? A stream is an abstraction of input or output, and `<<` writes the object's data in some way to a stream. The stream does already exist and nothing gets converted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need to convert your "class data" into an interim string stream with the `<<` overload you have.

2) You need to query the string object from the string stream object you have constructed and set.

3) You need to obtain the `QString` (or `QByteArray` for that matter) out of the string object.

4) You can set that particular `QString` for the `QTextStream` or `QDataStream` class.

Here is the code that would do the conversion for you in the proper Qt way:

```
std::stringstream myStringStream;
myStringStream << MyClassObject;
QTextStream textStream(QString::fromStdString(myStringStream.str()));
```

or

```
std::stringstream myStringStream;
myStringStream << MyClassObject;
QDataStream dataStream(QString::fromStdString(myStringStream.str()));
```

You could also use the `setString` method instead of the constructor to set the `QDataStream` and/or `QTextStream` up properly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a misunderstand of what a `istream` and `Q*Stream` represents. Think of them as pipes or tubes. They do not HOLD data, they just allow data to be moved from one place (the class object) to another place (a file or some such).

In other words, the data is not stored in the stream itself, so even if you COULD convert a `istream` to a `QDataStream`, it wouldn't help you in any way to retrieve the `myClass` object that was streamed out through the stream.

As suggested in the comment, one could do something like this:

```
stringstream ss;
QDataStream  ds;
myclass a;

...  do other stuff with a, such as give it some content... 

ss << a;

string s = ss.str();

ds << s;
```

(There may be other steps needed to convert a std::string to an object suitable for storing in a QDataStream, but the essence here is that you use a std::istream type object to get the data out of the class into a string, and then output the string to your QDataStream)

Comment: I know, how to convert to from string. problem is that how can I get the string from <<myClass

Comment: Like I said, use stringstream!

Comment: -1. There is no such a thing as `QStream`. Please fix that.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: No, there isn't a thing called QStream, there are however several flavours of streams in QT, such as QTextStream and QDataStream. How would you like me to rephrase the statement to encompass all the possible streams in QT? I'm happy to do that, but I fail to see how my use of the common name for all QT Streams `QStream` detracts from the answer...

Comment: @Mats: it is invalid. Moreover, QT != Qt. Please read the tag wiki about it...

Comment: I have inserted a * to indicate that I mean "any type of Q-something-stream", and I do appologise for the upper/lowercase confusion. I still maintain that this is not the essence of my answer, which you have just replicated (albeit yours has more detail).

Comment: As you have realized, I removed my -1 when you fixed the concern. QT is Quick Time, Qt is 'Q' toolkit. I did not replicate your answer. I wrote one from scratch using a proper Qt way because it seems that is the end result to achieve, so I thought I would prefer that.