# How to copy and paste a custom object in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm tring to copy and paste a custom object from `QListView` to an other window of the same application, but this class return just a `std::ostream`, and I don't have access to modify this class.

How can I put this std::ostream in `QDatastream` then `QClipboard` for copy and paste process?

```
void ProjectModel::copymodel(QModelIndex idx){

  const mo::model model(modelList.at(idx.row()));

  std::ostream *stream;
  stream << &model;

  QByteArray itemData;
  QDataStream datastream(&itemData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

  QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
  mimeData->setData("test", itemData);

  QApplication::clipboard()->setMimeData(mimeData);}
```

the custom class `mo::model` returns `std::stream` like that:

```
namespace mo {

::std::ostream& operator<< (::std::ostream& o, const model& i){
  o << ::std::endl << "name: " << i.name ();
  if (i.box ())
  {
    o << ::std::endl << "box: " << *i.box ();
  }

  for (model::basic_element_const_iterator
       b (i.basic_element ().begin ()), e (i.basic_element ().end ());
       b != e; ++b)
  {
    o << ::std::endl << "basic_element: " << *b;
  }

  for (model::net_const_iterator
       b (i.net ().begin ()), e (i.net ().end ());
       b != e; ++b)
  {
    o << ::std::endl << "net: " << *b;
  }

  for (model::com_position_const_iterator
       b (i.com_position ().begin ()), e (i.com_position ().end ());
       b != e; ++b)
  {
    o << ::std::endl << "com_position: " << *b;
  }

  if (i.com_truthtable ())
  {
    o << ::std::endl << "com_truthtable: " << *i.com_truthtable ();
  }

  if (i.com_pos_titles ())
  {
    o << ::std::endl << "com_pos_titles: " << *i.com_pos_titles ();
  }

  return o;}}
```

Comment: Show some code. How the external API looks like. What you can change? What data you want to copy to clipboard: text, graphics? And why is is a problem, use of clipboard in Qt is straight forward.

Comment: I want to convert std::ostream object Qdatastream.

Comment: Your code isn't compiling as it is (errors in your *copyModel* method). Could you provide a working example?

Comment: possible duplicate of  [std::ostream to QDataStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331120)